# Stripping specific chars from beginning/ending of a string

Tags: java, regex

Given a word-string in Java, I want to strip off from beginning and from end, exactly these specified set of characters:

```
[?:!.,;'\"«»]
```

as many times as they appear.

For instance, `«Be!!»` should become just `Be`, `"Here!!!"` should become `Here`, `«I` should become `I`.

Can anyone provide a correct way to do this?

Comment: In regex you can capture it like `[?:!.,;'\"«»]+(.*)[?:!.,;'\"«»]+` ;).

Comment: do you need to replace the characters in all words on just in the beginning/end of lines ?

Comment: Input is just a word string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an anchored regex in `string.replaceAll` function.

```
string.replaceAll("^[?:!.,;'\"«»]+|[?:!.,;'\"«»]+$", "");
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/gH0sC5/1)